# How to get all members names and address with this SQL design?

Tags: sql

I have the following design:

[image]

I know the design is not ideal but I am stuck with it.

I am trying to get all the member's names and address in one query (even if address is the same for Juvenile since they are linked to an Adult) ?

Comment: what database is this for. "SQL" is a language, but dbms vendors have different implementations of the lnguage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, each member can be either an adult or a juvenile. If he is an adult, then he has an address. If he is a juvenile, his address is the address of the adult, this juvenile is linked to, in that case you can try this:

```
Select mbrs.FirstName, mbrs.LastName, adls.Street, adls.City, adls.State, adls.ZIP  
    From Members mbrs Inner Join Adults adls  
    On mbrs.MemberNo = adls.MemberNo  
Union All  
Select mbrs.FirstName, mbrs.LastName, adls.Street, adls.City, adls.State, adls.ZIP  
    From Juvelines jvls Inner Join Members mbrs  
    On jvls.MemberNo = mbrs.MemberNo
    Inner Join Adults adls 
    On jvls.AdultMemberNo = adls.MemberNo
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: We do not encourage use of old "comma separated" syntax in the from clause e.g. `From Members mbrs, Adults adls  Where mbrs.MemberNo = adls.MemberNo` should be `From Members mbrs INNER JOIN Adults adls  ON mbrs.MemberNo = adls.MemberNo`

Comment: Okay thank you for this info. I will update my answer !

Comment: I agree. I've just corrected an incorrect join. Maybe it hadn't happened with explicit ANSI joins as they are easier to read and thus less prone to errors.

Comment: Also note how to format code (as code) basically it needs an indent f 4 chars from the left. There is a `{}` icon in the toolbar to assist you to do this too.

Comment: Yes I noticed how much this format helped in making my answer clearer, so I will make sure to do this in my next answers.

Comment: this only seems to return Adults

Comment: can I see an example of a juvenile not returning in the result please ? so we can debug it together.

Comment: You are welcome glad it worked!  
Keep the hard work!